# How to set up a Symfony Standard Edition application without vendor, but with PEAR

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, pear, zend-server

I'm following the basic description of [Symfony Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard) on how to set up a new application with Symfony 2.

The thing is, this and all other guides explains that I need to have a vendors directory, where I should place third part libraries, such as Doctrine, Swiftmailer and Symfony itself.

However, Zend Server PEAR already comes with almost all of those libraries. As you know, I can even update my Symfony and Doctrine versions with the pear update command.

The question is: how can I set up that basic application to effectively use my PEAR libraries and ignore the vendors directory?

This is my version of **app/autoload.php**:

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    'Sensio'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'JMS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
    'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
    'Monolog'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/src',
    'Assetic'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/assetic/src',
    'Metadata'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/metadata/src',
));
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    'Twig_Extensions_' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig-extensions/lib',
    'Twig_'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig/lib',
));

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->registerPrefixFallbacks(array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs'));
}

$loader->registerNamespaceFallbacks(array(
    __DIR__.'/../src',
));
$loader->register();

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(function($class) use ($loader) {
    $loader->loadClass($class);
    return class_exists($class, false);
});
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php');

// Swiftmailer needs a special autoloader to allow
// the lazy loading of the init file (which is expensive)
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php';
Swift::registerAutoload(__DIR__.'/../vendor/swiftmailer/lib/swift_init.php');
```

It's clear that the autoloader is being configured to load the libraries from the vendor directory. I wanna use the libraries that comes with the pear package, however. How would that be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit app/autoload.php to point to your pear delivered packages.  Be careful that you use the proper versions.  Probably be safer to just use the packages delivered with Symfony and then add paths to any additional libraries.

Comment: Ok, that may work. However, since the libraries are in the pear directory, wouldn't it be right that they get autoloader automatically, just like Zend Framework components would be (since they are in my include path, just as the pear package)?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  S2 ships with an autoload.php file.  If you use it then you will need to adjust it.  If you use some other autoload strategy then no.  S2 is built around namespaces so your autoload strategy will need to accommodate those.  Might be best to just bring down the S2 zip file and play around with the demo app.

Comment: Let me try and explain it in a more clear way: if you create an index.php file and try to reference a Zend Framework class, for instance, Zend_Controller_Action, since Zend Framework is on php's include path, it will load correctly, right? If Doctrine, Symfony and all others are, just like that, in the pear package, on the php's include path as well, they should load automatically without the need for an autoloader, right? Or am I incredibly wrong?

Comment: Incredibly wrong might be a bit of an overstatement.  Might start by looking here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php.  You actually need some code that translates Zend_Controller_Action into require 'Zend/Controller/Action'.  And that is where autoloading comes in.  Include paths are only part of the story.  And once again, bring down S2 and work through the demo.  It's is all explained.